# How would I write a rule that detects an email attachment that has a random name, is a .xls, and has a specific file size?

Tags: email, email-attachments, pcre, filesize, snort

Trying to write a rule that would detect email traffic coming into the network that is:

1. Sent to a specific domain (example, gmail.com)
2. Is a .xls file
3. Has a filename that can be up to 75 bytes in name length
4. Is an email attachment, and this attachment is a specific size that is known and never changes (example, the attachment is 100000 bytes in size)

Note to others, I am a beginner at snort. That out of the way, I've only managed this so far:

```
content:"|05|gmail|03|com|00|"; nocase; pcre:"/([a-zA-Z0-9] {1,75}\.xls)";
```

Not sure how to get the file size attachment detection in there, or even if the pcre bit for detecting the filename and type are correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure rule 3 can either be shortened down to "Has a filename with a maximum length of 75" or have to be rewritten completely. The title seems to suggest you want to detect random filenames. If you figure out a way to do that, I'm pretty sure you're set for life.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used snort, but from the informations that I gleaned in the documentation, it seems that your pattern can be written like that:

- if only letters and digits are allowed in the filename:

  > ```
  > pcre:"/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,75}\.xls$/"
  > ```
- otherwise *(to allow any kind of characters for the filename)*:

  > ```
  > pcre:"/\/[^\/]{1,75}\.xls$/"
  > ```

Note that according to the examples in the documentation, the pattern needs to be enclosed between delimiters *(slashes here)*. Consequence, all the literal slashes must be escaped in the pattern.

Comment: To clarify: The main problem Casimir has spotted is the space in the pcre. What you wrote would mean an alphanumeric character, followed by spaces (from 1 to 75 of them), then `.xls`. Strings such as: `h                   .xls`. (BTW I don't know the system you're using, so I don't know whether it returns true if the string doesn't match the regex but a substring of it does.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out about the white space. I've never been to sure about the delimiter use. I know the "/" is the delimiter, but what use does the "\" have? So it appears that the criteria for 1 - 3 have been met, but has anyone found a way to do number 4? My current rule now reads like this: alert tcp !$INTERNAL 1024: -> $INTERNAL 25 (msg:"Malicious EMAIL Attachment"; flow:established, to_server; content:"|05|gmail|03|com|00|"; nocase; pcre:"/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,75}\.xls$/";)

Comment: @markdario12: Since `/` is the delimiter, to avoid ambiguity, all literal `/` must be escaped with a backslash `\/` (otherwise the parser will believe that the *(literal)* slash is the end delimiter)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the explanation. Would the pcre work the same if there were no slashes at all?

Comment: @markdario12: delimiters seems to be needed with snort *(in many languages delimiters are needed for regex patterns, and are by default slashes)*, however I don't know if you can choose an other delimiter character instead of the slash. But if your question is *can I write a pattern without using a literal slash*, the answer is no for the second pattern, however you can try to use `"/[^\/]{1,75}\.xls$/"` instead. For the first pattern, you can't remove the begining literal slashes without obtain false results.